# Generic directive in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am writing one angularjs directive which can be reusable across the application

```
<div ><div ng-controller="ctrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/checkbox.html">
<div ng-repeat="obj in data">
<input on-check type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" value="{{obj}}" click-checkbox="checkstatus(checked,obj)" checked-me="checked" />{{obj}}</div>

</script>
<check-boxes getType="data"></check-boxes>
<check-boxes getType="bestnights"></check-boxes>

</div></div>
```

On attribute change the directive should use ng-repeat on gettype and iterate using controller and return object for each array.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){


  $scope.data=['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
  var daysArray=[]; 
  $scope.checkStatus=function(checked, obj){
  var index=daysArray.indexOf(obj);
   if(checked){
   if(index === -1){
   daysArray.push(obj);
   }  }

  if(!checked){
  daysArray.splice(index,1);
   }
  var str=daysArray.toString();
  console.log(str);
  console.log(checked);
  };


  });
  app.directive('checkBoxes',function(){
   return{
    restrict:"EA",  
    controller:"ctrl",
    templateUrl:"partials/checkbox.html",
    link:function(scope, ele, attrs,dctrl){
    ele.bind('click',function(){  
    });
     }
    };
    });

       app.directive('onCheck',function(){
   return{
     restrict:"A",
     scope:{
       clickCheckbox:"&",
     value:"@",  
     checkedMe:"="
    },
     link:function(scope,ele, attrs){
    ele.bind('click',function(){
    console.log(scope.value);
    });
    }
    };
  });
```

I made on jsbin here [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wajahofozu/4/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: On attribute change the directive should use ng-repeat on gettype and iterate using controller and return object for each array. There are two array for now, which are using array name in gettype attribute of directive. I want to use those attribute and set the array in controller.

Comment: sorry my friend, your code is not readable at all, use spaces to make logical blocks. anyway: <check-boxes getType="data">  variable name 'getType' is wrong, should be 'get-type'. before splitting to directive, try to make it working in single html and controller, and after line by line split into simple directives.

Comment: I made one JSBin also http://jsbin.com/wajahofozu/4/edit?html,js,console,output